# Cookies are retained even after explicit delete in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, safe-browsing

I need to be able to delete my entire browsing history in IE8. Even after explicitly invoking the option of clearing browsing history from within IE8, I notice some cookies and files do not get deleted from the Temporary Internet Files folder.

Comment: FYI: type this into your address bar-> 'shell:cookies' without single quotes, it will show you the folder with the cookies that exist still

Answer (score 12):

instead of going to tools -> internet options -> delete... it seems IE has a 'feature' to save data for your frequent websites, so deleting cookies does not always delete cookies.

If you instead go to Tools -> Delete Browsing History -> uncheck 'Preserve Favorites website data' -> then delete cookies, this removes all cookies like it should have in the first place

I don't know why IE8 thought having the Preserve Favorites checkmarked by default was a good idea, but whatever floats there boat! -Jaseowns

Comment: I had this same issue, it's really lame how vague IE is about which sites it will preserve data for. It just decides for you? LOL! Thanks for posting this solution, worked for me.

Comment: You saved me on this one... *HIGH FIVE*!!